# Why is my Antlr4 grammar accepting empty strings as valid numbers?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

Here is an Antlr4 grammar to parse single-digit numbers:

```
    grammar SortFormula;
    DECIMAL: [0-9] '.' [0-9] ;
    INTEGER: [0-9] ;
    number: INTEGER | DECIMAL ;
```

When I parse the empty string "" using this grammar, I get an empty `number` context with no tokens and no errors. I would expect parsing to have failed instead because the `number` rule requires *at least one token* (obviously, right?). This is leading my program to accept inputs like `sqrt()` as valid even though `sqrt` doesn't work without a parameter.

**When I change the definition of `number` to be either integer or decimal exclusively:**

`number: INTEGER;`
works as expected; parsing fails on empty string input. Likewise `number: DECIMAL;` also triggers the parsing failure as expected.

BUT when I try to do `number: INTEGER | DECIMAL;` suddenly it adds some secret case to the lexer that allows empty strings to slip through.

Things I have tried:

- Rearranging the ordering of the lexer rules
- Adding or removing `fragment` rules, for example defining `fragment DIGIT: [0-9];` and defining `INTEGER` in terms of that.
- Changing the promiscuity of capture rules; `[0-9]+`, `DIGIT*`, etc.
- Adding more parentheses and subrules to parser rules, e.g. `int: INTEGER;`
- `number: ( INTEGER | DECIMAL ) EOF;`
- Copying the number parsing grammars from the Antlr4 reference book source materials. They have the same problem. For example, this grammar isolated out of `/examples/R.g4`:

```
    grammar R;
    expr:
        INT
        | FLOAT
        | COMPLEX;
    
    INT:  DIGIT+ [Ll]? ;
    
    FLOAT: 
        DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT* EXP? [Ll]?
        |   DIGIT+ EXP? [Ll]?
        |   '.' DIGIT+ EXP? [Ll]?;
    
    fragment DIGIT:  '0'..'9' ; 
    fragment EXP: ('E' | 'e') ('+' | '-')? INT ;
    
    COMPLEX:
        INT 'i'
        | FLOAT 'i'
        ;
```

Is `[0-9]` somehow matching the EOF token? Is there an error I'm just not seeing at parse time? Am I mixing up lexing and parsing rules? Am I misinterpreting what a "valid parse tree" actually means in my assertions?

Comment: I can't reproduce your results for an empty string (with either grammar, both give reasonable errors).  And `sqrt()` isn't accounted for in either grammar.

Comment: Always always always augment the start rule with EOF. `number: (INTEGER | DECIMAL) EOF ;`, then try again.

Comment: Please include the precise test you are using, and why you think its results imply that the parse did not fail.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently my definition of a "parsing failure" is different from Antlr's.

When parsing empty string with `number: INTEGER ;` I would end up with a "valid" parse tree consisting of an error node that reported `[0]  {<missing INTEGER>}`. But with `number: INTEGER | DECIMAL;` the parse tree ended up being a `number` node, with no error nodes (and no children in general). My overall program (C#, by the way) used a visitor to evaluate the math expressions and which relied on `VisitErrorNode()` to detect whether a part of the input expression had problems. In the second case, no error nodes existed so they weren't reporting as failures.

Implementing a `BaseErrorListener` and attaching it using `parser.AddErrorListener(new MyErrorListener());` correctly began reporting a syntax error in both cases when attempting to match empty string, so I guess that's the solution.

Comment: It's not Antlr's definition of "parsing failure", since as you say Antlr reports the error if you're listing for it. What it doesn't necessarily do is insert an error node in the AST. (I agree that it's easy to be misled by that behaviour.)

Comment: My guess is that you are using Antlr4cs, the old/unmaintained C# fork of Antlr4, package reference "antlr4 4.6.6". It doesn't print out an error message for an empty input file with your grammar, with or without EOF-augmented start rules. Antlr4.runtime.standard does. You should use the official Antlr code.